# Documentation on MyBase?

Tags: database, delphi, tclientdataset

Can anyone provide me a link to a documentation or some examples of MyBase used with Delphi (newer versions) and especially basic operations (adding, modifying, deleting, searching ...)

Thank you.

Comment: Note that MyBase is a synonym for ClientDataSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent introduction from Cary Jensen can be found here http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28876
This is actually only the first article in a series from Cary Jensen. For an overview of the other articles see here http://gp.embarcadero.com/authors/edit/3030.aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/a/tclientdataset.htm

Answer (score 0):

Jensen has a new book called [Delphi in Depth: ClientDataSets](http://amzn.com/1461008581). It's a great read.